# Notification when transition completes

Tags: angularjs, animation

I use Angular 1.3.1, `ngAnimate` with CSS transitions. And I want to know when the CSS transition starts and completes.

I was expecting to be able to use `module.animation` but it does not work as I expect it (and as the docs suggest). I'm not able to get a notification when the transition completes.

I have created a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UGCmbBoiLT1xvhx7JGst.

This is my HTML code:

```html
<body ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
<h1>Angular Animation issue!</h1>
<div class="animation" id="resizeme" ng-class="ctrl.className"></div>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.className"
         ng-true-value="'big'" ng-false-value="''">
  Bigger!
</label>
```

This is the CSS code:

```css
#resizeme {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: width linear 1s;
  transition: width linear 1s;
}
#resizeme.big {
  width: 200px;
}
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```js
var module = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

module.controller('Controller', function() {
  this.className = '';
});

module.animation('.animation', function() {
  return {
    addClass: function(elemennt, className) {
      console.log('addClass animation starts');
      return function(cancel) {
        console.log('addClass animation completes')
      }
    },
    removeClass:  function(elemennt, className) {
      console.log('removeClass animation starts');
      return function(cancel) {
        console.log('removeClass animation completes')
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Checking the checkbox runs the "addClass" animation. I do get the "addClass animation starts" message in the console, but I don't get the "addClass animation completes" message when the transition is complete.

The [Javascript-defined Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) section of `ngAnimate` docs says the following for the function returned by `enter`, `addClass` and friends:

```
//this (optional) function will be called when the animation
//completes or when the animation is cancelled (the cancelled
//flag will be set to true if cancelled).
```

So I'd expect the function that outputs "addClass animation completes" to be called when the transition completes. But it's not called.

Does anyone know how I can get a notification when the transition completes?

PS: I know I could use the `$animate` service and the promise returned by `$animate.addClass`. But I'm trying to use `ng-class` (and other animation-compatible Angular directives), so I don't have access to the promise provided by the `$animate` service.